# IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.2 to create the Servlet class, but the Name and package cannot be defined in the New Servlet, as shown in the figure

Tags: java, intellij-idea, servlets

I have used IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.2 to create a new web project, and added Tomcat Servlet-api.jar package, click the src file, select 【new】--> [servlet] JAVAEE TYPE appears; Entity Name; The Class Name. I was confused about this aspect and searched for it myself, trying again and again without finding a solution.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grNUq.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usHiD.png)
The following is the method required by the school: The idea version is the previous.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tR6KE.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuh1D.png)

Hopefully, there will be a solution to this by defining the Name and specifying the package in the New Servlet interface. The IDEA tool automatically generates Servlet code. To better demonstrate how the Servlet works, add some code to the doGet() and doPost() methods.

Comment: See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-316701/Cannot-create-servlet-web-filter-web-listener-after-2023.1-update. Original templates are attached to the linked issue and you can add them in the IDE manually.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: "Rarely used". Wow.